# How to pass variable from one html to a php file

Tags: php, html, xampp

login.html file contains :

```
<A HREF="welcome.php?name=Kevin"> Hi, I'm Kevin! </A>
```

welcome.php file contains :

```
<?php 
$name = $_GET['name']; 
echo( "Welcome to our Web site, $name!" ); 
?>
```

While I run login.html it redirect to welcome.php but gives following error:
*Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\train\welcome.php on line 2
Welcome to our Web site, !*

Comment: when you say you redirect, you meen you click the link we can see, right? Because if you'd do a real redirect it would be smth completely different. ?

Comment: Yes, when I click on "Hi, I'm Kevin!" link it goes to the page welcome.php

Comment: can you do var_dump($_GET) in welcome.php when you click on the href ?

Comment: $name = var_dump($_GET); Same result. Am i getting this syntax correct ?

Comment: no, above $name = $_GET['name']; do var_dump($_GET);. Also on welcome.php how does your link look like ?

Comment: var_dump($_GET); gives the same result. On welcome.php i get only the message "Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\train\welcome.php on line 2
Welcome to our Web site, !

Comment: But does your link look something like welcome.php?name=Kevin ?

Comment: Yes, it gives the output "Welcome to our Web site, !" As you can see the name variable is missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104775/discussion-between-vasil-shaddix-and-ayaz).

Comment: Problem is solved after re-starting xampp. Also in welcome.php changed the 2nd line : 
echo "Welcome to our website, " . $_GET['name'];